# How do I fix the foreign key constraints?

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles(
        type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        year INT(4),
        cost INT(10),
        model VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        manufacturer VARCHAR(20),
        country VARCHAR(20),
        licensename VARCHAR(20),
        stock INT(3),
        PRIMARY KEY (type, model)
);

CREATE TABLE Staff(
        sid CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
        phoneno INT(10),
        taxfile INT(9),
        salary INT(10),
        fname VARCHAR(20),
        lname VARCHAR(20),
        hours INT(4),
        PRIMARY KEY (sid)
);

CREATE TABLE Customers(
        cid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        fname VARCHAR(20),
        lname VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY (cid)
);

CREATE TABLE ContactDetails(
        value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        type ENUM ("phone", "email"),
        cid INT,
        FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers(cid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY (value, cid)
);

CREATE TABLE Sales(
        rego CHAR(7),
        salesprice INT(15),
        time DATE,
        comm INT(15),
        warrantee DATE,
        cid INT,
        sid CHAR(6),
        type VARCHAR(10),
        model VARCHAR(20),
        FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers(cid) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Staff(sid) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES Vehicles(type) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (model) REFERENCES Vehicles(model) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY (rego)
);
                                                                                                                                                                                          
CREATE TABLE License(
        name CHAR(30),
        expdate DATE,
        gdate DATE,
        cid INT,
        sid CHAR(6),
        FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers(cid) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Staff(sid) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY (name, sid, cid)
);

CREATE TABLE Interact(
        time DATE,
        cid INT,
        sid CHAR(6),
        type VARCHAR(10),
        FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customers(cid) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Staff(sid) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY (time, cid, sid)
);

COMMIT;
```

OUTPUT
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

The problem is with the Sales Table, but I can't see the syntax

Comment: Foreign keys must reference either a primary key or a unique key. In your Vehicles table, neither type or model is unique (the combination is unique, but not the indivdual columns). So foreign keys in the Sales table can't reference them.

Comment: Note that `varchar(10)` doesn't take up any less space than a `varchar(255)`. It just limits the maximum size to 10 characters and, unless you have strict SQL mode on, truncates the rest. Unless you have a clear reason to limit the maximum size of a column there's no need to be stingy. `int(3)` does not limit it to 999 but it is a display width of dubious value. `time` is a reserved word and should be avoided as a column name, especially since it's a `date`. Consider `sold_at`. Finally, unless you plan on selling no vehicle be sure to set your foreign key columns `not null`.

Answer (score 0):

Vehicles has a compound primary key `PRIMARY KEY (type, model)`. This must also be used as the foreign key in a single declaration.

```
FOREIGN KEY (type, model) REFERENCES Vehicles(type, model) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

You'll probably want `on delete cascade` as well.

I recommend using simple auto incrementing integer primary keys. They're more compact, simpler, and avoid all the `ON UPDATE CASCADE`s.

Comment: so delete all the UPDATE CASCADES in every table?

Comment: @i_dont_know *If and only if* you switch to an integer primary key Otherwise they ensure the foreign keys will be updated if the vehicle type or model changes.